# Calling A Bash Script and Giving Path To File

Tags: bash, macos, shell, homebrew

This could be a dumb question, but how do I make it so a script can be called with "sh [Script Name] [File Path]" and have the script automatically read the file path?

For instance, if I use `cp ~/usr/local/bin/testScript ~/Desktop` it knows that the target file is the testScript file because it read the path from the command line.

I have a script based on ImageMagick that prompts the user for the file path using "read", processes it, and then drops it onto the desktop. I want the script to skip the actual prompt for the file path, and instead just target whatever file path is entered after calling the script (I.E. `sh ConvertPDF /Users/ProfileName/Desktop/testFile.tiff`

Answer (score 2):

Positional parameters to the script are available via `$n` where `n` >= 1. For `n` > 9 braces are required in order to distinguish from `n` < 10.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$2" "$3" "$1"
```

...

```
$ ./somescript foo bar 42
```

Comment: Any way you can dumb this down a bit for me. Still pretty new to Bash

Comment: Dollar sign. Number. Doesn't get any more dumbed down than that.

Comment: So I looked into it, and if I understand it correctly, $n references the n'th argument written into the command. Is this correct?

Comment: Passed to the script, yes.